# Different response code based on fetch method?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to figure out if a certain URL exists or not by checking the response code, but I seem to have found some strange behavior.

```
fetch(url, { method: "HEAD" })
```

Running the line above gives me a response code of 200.

```
fetch(url)
```

Ruinning the line above without the method gives me a response code of 404 which is also what I see in my browser and by 2 different "check response code websites".

Am I making a logical mistake here or is that up to spec?
Or might this be some common thing for servers to do to prevent crawling?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's simply because the API you're calling is configured to respond to a HEAD request for the URL you're using, but not a GET request. I would presume that it's due to CORS and that HEAD/POST will work instead.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch), we see that the second parameter is the `options`, which is... Optional.

Now, what is the method if it's not specified, as in your case when you specify only the first parameter? You can find the answer [here](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-fetch-in-javascript).

> The default method of fetch() is GET. If needed, we can also make a POST, PUT and DELETE method request as well. Below is an example of fetch() using the POST method.

Since in your first call you didn't specify anything for `options`, the request method was GET. In your second call you specified it to be HEAD, hence the request method in your two examples were different.

Conclusion: the endpoint you are to trigger supports HEAD requests, but does not support GET requests, at least in the manner you have sent it. To find out whether it supports GET requests at all and if so, what you need to do to get a proper response, you either need to contact the owner and ask, or, somehow manage to send a GET request successfully and then study that request, see what the headers and parameters are.

Comment: What makes me confused is that Mozilla Dev states "The HEAD method asks for a response identical to a GET request, but without the response body.". Isn't it expected to be the same, but easier on bandwith? Just for clarification I am checking if a newspaper article exits. I've got a CMS ID that might lead to an article or an image which require different url formatting. Do I'm checking weather querying for an article with that ID gives me 404 or not.

Comment: @JasonTS The developers of the website you are to reach may have decided to reject GET requests for that particular endpoint. I can set a webserver to give you an error if you try to reach a certain endpoint via a GET request while serve you if you send a HEAD request. Furthermore, if I expect some parameter for any GET requests or some validations to be fulfilled, like being connected to a VPN, then I can set my app code to throw the same error. So, this seems to be more a policy of the owner of the website than a programming problem.